# Access to class inside the static object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Please help me to access from inside the static navigationOptions to Page1 class.
FYI  please don't advice to use **.this** as it doesn't work, and it is obligatory to use static in navigationOptions .

```
class Page1 extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isCollapsed:false
        }
    }
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: () => (
            <View style={{
                flexDirection:'row',
                alignItems:'center',
                justifyContent:'space-around',
                width:'100%'
            }}>
                <Text>Page 1</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.9}
                    onPress={() => this.setState({isCollapsed:!this.state.isCollapsed})}
                >
                    <Icon
                        name='plus'
                        type='entypo'
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.isCollapsed}>
                    <Text>Items...</Text>
                </Collapsible>
            </View>
        ),
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Page 1</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Static members cannot access values and properties of an instance of a class using `this` as the static method is a property of the class rather than the particular instance. See [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx).
You could do the infamous 'self' hack by declaring `var self = null` globally and then assigning `self = this` inside the constructor.

Comment: *"You could do the infamous 'self' hack by declaring `var self = null` globally and then assigning `self = this` inside the constructor."* That assumes there will always only be a single instance of the class?